# Styling issues with tinymce in solid-start

Tags: tinymce, solid-start

I am trying to use tinymce in a solid-start project. TinyMCE is opening when I need to but it is not showing the toolbar, and is not actually letting me edit. I suspect this is a style issue.
I reproduced this in a simpler codebase at:
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/franckdervaux/solid-start-tinymce/main?import=true&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00073b5u0fk0vhwz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00033b5uazw4askz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00053b5urtp6hn44%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00063b5uwpc3xg15%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clnbfontw00033b5uazw4askz%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00023b5u6dwa9ris%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00033b5uazw4askz%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00023b5u6dwa9ris%2522%257D%252C%2522clnbfontw00063b5uwpc3xg15%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00063b5uwpc3xg15%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnbfoz2e009w3b5uxh56x9q0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfoy2x00783b5ulccbkbh5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3001%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfoz2e009w3b5uxh56x9q0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clnbfontw00053b5urtp6hn44%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00053b5urtp6hn44%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00043b5urqiur0yp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfontw00043b5urqiur0yp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clnbfonz0000oe7hk7pzx4di2%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnbfou5q00673b5uk11sneo2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). Just click the button "Click to edit" to see the problem.

Any idea?

Update:
I was able to improve things by adding some more imports:

```
import 'tinymce/icons/default/icons'
import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme'
import 'tinymce/models/dom/model'
```

Now the text can be edited. However, TinyMCE toolbars are still not displayed ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by adding:
`import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.css'`

Thank you to [TinyMCE with Laravel 10 and vite](https://laracoding.com/how-to-add-tinymce-using-laravel-10-and-vite/) who inspired me for the solution!